# Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) with curl not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've been using FCM messaging for a while to submit push notifications to Chrome web browser.

However, my code is now broken and I can't find a reason why. I'm using curl on Mac Terminal to send the messages:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: key=THE_KEY" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
    "to" : "/topics/topicname",
    "priority" : "high",
     "notification" : {
        "body" : "Article Title",
        "title" : "Website Name",
        "click_action": "Link.com",
    }
}' "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
```

I'm checkin the documentation but everything seems to be just fine. Any idea why it would stop working for no reason? I don't get any error message on the terminal, it just doesn't do anything.

If there is a code issue it has to be to send the message. Even if the website code is broken, there are thousands of browsers already registered do receive the notification, but no one is receiving.

Comment: I thought "to:" field had to be a token generated by the service worker.

Comment: That's how it's supposed to add the topic according to the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/topic-messaging

Comment: For those wondering, the current code is 100% working. I guess FCM service was down that day. Now it's currently working.

Comment: FYI: they do have tech support "https://firebase.google.com/support" that lists status right on top. May not be the last outage???